# `$ bundle install` throws the error: bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I installed ruby recently in my system using the command `sudo snap install ruby --classic`.

```sh
$ which ruby
/snap/bin/ruby
$ which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

Following the advice from another stackoverflow question, I added the following line to my `.bashrc`

`export PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin:/usr/local/bin/"`

However when I try to setup things in my Jekyll project using the command `bundle install`, I get the following error:

`bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: try re-installing the bundler gem

Comment: @benjessop Could you tell me how to that?

Comment: gem uninstall bundler;
gem install bundler

Comment: I would really recommend that you DON'T use the snap to install a system ruby. What you really want is to install a ruby version manager such as rbenv, rvm, chruby or asdf and uses it manage ruby installations. This error really has nothing to do with bundler. Rather the snap messed up the ruby installation or your path.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this

> gem install bundler

Answer (score 0):

Like max said:

> I would really recommend that you DON'T use the snap to install a
> system ruby. What you really want is to install a ruby version manager
> such as rbenv, rvm, chruby or asdf and uses it manage ruby
> installations. This error really has nothing to do with bundler.
> Rather the snap messed up the ruby installation or your path. –  max

The issue for me was that using snap, switched to rbenv and everything works!