# Cannot run ruby/bundle script from WSL 'bash script.sh' command line, but OK from a bash interpreter 'sh script.sh'

Tags: ruby, bash, jekyll, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bundler

I have successfully installed ruby in my WSL2 environment on Windows 11 using the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt install gnupg2 build-essential dh-autoreconf
$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ...
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
$ rvm install ruby
$ gem update
$ gem install jekyll
$ gem install bundler
```

After that, the installed ruby version is 3.1.3p185 (that's what I get when running `ruby --version`)

Consider now the following `test.sh` script that I have in my WSL home directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle exec jekyll build
```

When I open a bash command prompt (using Win+R then typing bash), I can successfully run:

```
$ sh test.sh
```

In this case, the Jekyll build runs fine.

Now, if, from a Powershell (or Windows CMD prompt) I type:

```
$ bash test.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Why? I have many other .sh scripts that I can run fine using the `bash script.sh` syntax.

I found the following question

[`$ bundle install` throws the error: bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910677/bundle-install-throws-the-error-bash-usr-local-bin-bundle-usr-bin-ruby2)

but unfortunately the proposed fix does not work (I already have `bundler` installed).

EDIT: using `wsl -e bash test.sh` instead of `bash test.sh` produces the same error. Also, if `test.sh` just contains `ruby --version`, I get `ruby: command not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `test.sh` script to:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm use 3.1.3 --install
bundle exec jekyll build
```

Save changes and run again:

```bash
bash test.sh
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: I find your answer useful and satisfying, however it might be preferable not to know about rvm's internal path declaration details - which might change over time. In this case, using the approach provided below (using 'bash -l') is better, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from ruby, which PATH was set up in `.bashrc`, and indeed `.bash_profile`, too. The solution is to run bash as a login shell (`bash -l`).